# Why my laptop works best when charging is low

Tags: charging

I have Lenovo B570 laptop with 2GB RAM, intel i3 processor and 500 GB hard disk having Windows 8.1. I have noticed that the performance in terms of how quickly the apps and windows open gets better when it is low on battery charge, about 20-30% remaining.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you verify this in any way? Typically the case is just the opposite.

Comment: Unless at low charge, it starts disabling things to save power.